# c++ Calling a different class method with a for loop

Tags: c++, class, loops, for-loop, implementation

im trying to call a different class method using the [i].display(); function
the error im getting i as follows:  `no operator "[]" matches these operands`

Here is my relevant code:
Main.cpp:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    char date_description[7];
    double high = 0.0, low = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter Date :";
    cin.getline(date_description, 80, '\n');
    cout << "Enter High :";
    cin >> high;
    cout << "Enter Low :";
    cin >> low;
    cin.ignore();
    weather.set(date_description, low, high);

  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Weather report:\n";
  cout << "======================" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      weather[i].display();
  }
```

Weather.cpp

```
void Weather::set(const char* date_description, double low , double high) {
        strcpy(date, date_description);
        highTemp = high;
        lowTemp = low;

    }

    void Weather::display() const {

    }
```

Any idea why my weather[i].display();
is throwing an error? 
I didnt code my display() implementation yet.

Comment: How did you define `weather`, especially the overloads of `[]` operator?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry im new to the language/terminology,i defined it at the top using this:  Weather weather;

Comment: What do you imagine `[i].display()` is supposed to do?  If `weather[i]` meant something the `weather[i].display()` would invoke display() on the object that is the result of `weather[i]`.  But since operator[] was not defined for your object weather, it means nothing.

Comment: @andirew, "What do you mean?" -- he means, in effect, what makes you think that the expression `weather[i]` should be meaningful?

Comment: Sorry for typo, I'm asking about `Weather` (the type), not `weather` (the variable).

Comment: Do i define it as Weather weather[]; ?

Comment: show us the line with declares the variable `weather` please.

Comment: Yes. I think you want to have an array of Weather, like `Weather weather[7];`. You cannot index a single object (unless you define that operator). If you have an unknown number of "weathers" you can use a `vector<Weather>`.

Comment: To understand this: Andirew, what do you **think** `weather[i]` should be doing?

Comment: Yes, if you had declared `weather` as `Weather weather[];` then `weather[i].display()` could be correct.  But if that is the full declaration and definition it would not be correct, you would need a size.  And then your use of `weather.set(` would need to be corrected to be consistent.

Comment: Ohh Alright that makes alot more sense now, is there a way to set my array for weather with a non constant value, example would be an amount the user would enter? Weather weather[n]; for example

Comment: Use a vector and `push_back()`.

Comment: Using the non constant n in a C array is a C99 feature that many C++ compiler accept.  But it is not standard C++.  Using a std::vector instead of a C array is better.

Comment: For my specific program, using a constant Array number for my Weather weather[] may cause problems depending on the users input, it needs to dynamic and change.. how would i implement std::vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       weather[i].display();  }
```

This is interpreted as:

weather is an array of pointers and you are calling display on i'th weather object in the weather array.

ex: Weather weather[10];

This would then make sense if it was declared as above.

You could also declare it as:

```
Weather* weather;
weather = new Weather[10];
```

Comment: Can i use Weather weather [n] n being a variable the user enters

Comment: if you want to allocate dynamically, use Weather* weather;weather = new Weather[n];

Answer (score 0):

We're missing a bit of code from your question, but I'm assuming that somewhere you've got

```
Weather weather(/*constructor args*/);
```

or just

```
Weather weather;
```

The error you are getting is the compiler saying "Hey, I tried to do [] on something of type "Weather", but the class doesn't know how to do that".

It looks like (from `weather[i].display()` and the two for-loops) that you're expecting that you have a list (either a vector or an array) of Weather objects, and trying to call display on each in turn.

The approach would be to instead start with

```
Weather weather[/*some integer*/];
```

or

```
std::vector<Weather> weather;
```

and to change the line `weather.set(date_description, low, high);` to also apply to each item in turn (e.g. `weather[i].set(date_description, low, high);`)